# Flatness of the $p$-th power roots ideals in a perfect ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, flatness

Let $A$ be a perfect ring of characteristic $p>0$. If $x\in A$ is a
 nonzero divisor then 
$$
(x^{1/p^{\infty}})=\bigcup_{e=1}^{\infty}(x^{1/p^{e}})A
$$ 
is an $A$-flat ideal.

Reading Hochster's *Canonical Elements in Local Cohomology Modules and the Direct Summand Conjecture*, I came across with this statement above and and I have been stuck for days trying to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(x^\infty)$ is a direct limit of principal ideals (which are free $A$-modules, hence flat). Now use that direct limit is exact and commutes with tensor products.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Definitely I should have been able to see that.